# phpDocumentor @global and @name question

Tags: php, global-variables, phpdoc

First day I use [phpDocumentor](http://phpdoc.org/) and so far so good, but I have a question that I didn't catch in the manual... The documentation of global variables.

How would I document this code if:

1. $someGlobalVar is **not** decalren in the PHP file of the class (it can even be undelared).
2. $someGlobalVar is declared like this: *$someGlobalVar = array();* (not using the superglobal array like in the phpDocumentor manual).

The PHP code:

```
class myCustomClass
{
    private $someProperty;

    //I want to document the use of global var in this method
    public function getSomeProperty()
    {
        global $someGlobalVar;

        if (isset($someGlobalVar))
        {
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I want do document these globals as the manual shows but I'm not sure how/where to put the @global and @name tags.

**Edit 2:** I ended up using the following snippet just before the declaration of getSomeProperty:

```
/**
 * Get some property based on the $someGlobalVar global.
 * @global array $someGlobalVar User defined array that bla bla bla.
 * @return mixed Return a result bla bla bla.
 */
```

I use phpDocumentor syntax so that the [NetBeans IDE](http://www.netbeans.org/) display inline help in the source code. All seems right in NetBeans but I'm not sure it's the way to do...

Anyone can confirm it's OK?

Comment: Well, **I** would solve this problem by not using globals :) But I don't think thats the answer you want.

Comment: Hehe true, but in my case I must document what has been done :)

Comment: For anyone getting here when Googling the problem, [this thread seems to have a detailed answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163292/phpdoc-does-not-seem-to-recognize-global-variables-in-output-what-am-i-doing-wr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $someGlobalVar is user defined and after some research I think [@uses](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.uses.pkg.html) is the most suited way to document this:

```
@uses $someGlobalVar User defined array that bla bla bla.
```

From the documentation:

> The @uses tag may be used to document
>   any element (global variable, include,
>   page, class, function, define, method,
>   variable)

Answer (score 1):

You would document the variable where it is defined I believe, e.g.

```
/**
 * My var
 * @var array
 */
$someGlobalVar = array();
```

You don't need to document it within your class method as you document the API and it's functionality.

My opinion anyway.